# No input / signal when playing game

Tags: drivers, hardware-failure, troubleshooting

I have a PC with the following. Specs (not overclocked):

Asus P7P55D LE (Motherboard),
Core i7-860 @ 2.8 GHz,
nVidia Geforce GTX 295 (with 2 GPUs),
4 GB Ram (1600 MHz, 9-9-9-24, 1,50v),
SATA HDD (500 GB)

When my son play his game: RuneScape, he gets black screen (usally) real quick and it says "No input / signal", but the PC is still running. I can sometimes press the "Num Lock" or "Caps Lock" key and see the change of the LED light on the keyboard, sometimes not. CTRL + ALT + DEL does not seem to have any effect and I'm forced to cut the power and start the PC up again

I have tried to reproduce the bug with Heaven benchmark and Prime95 and i can not reproduce the error. However i noticed that the core temps, whent uptill 100 degrees with Prime95 and i think CPU needs new thermal paste, but this is not the problem for've kept an eye on the temps when he plays Runescape and when the error occurs the core temps is very fine (60-70 degrees )

Both heaven benchmark (Basic and Extreme) and Prime95 has been allowed to go for 1 hour each without any problems. I also tested the RAM with memtest86 and found no errors

Furthermore I have tried to format the PC and reinstalled drivers, etc. and same error when playing Runescape

I had Win 7 to begin with and upgraded to win 10

I wonder what might be wrong? Or what to test next?

Comment: I recall some specific games in the past that would do this. I think Ghost Recon Advanced Warfighter (GRAW) had this issue on my system and IIRC it had to do with an interaction between "deferred rendering" and "render frames ahead" setting in the GPU drivers. If you have access to a driver setting called "max number of frames to render in advance" try reducing it to 1 or 0

Comment: Found a setting in nVidia CP called "Maximum pre-rendered frames" under specific program settings, and changed it to 1 (No option for 0) and so far not crashed (10mins)

Comment: Unfortunately, the error still shows :(

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention your PSU model. It's possible that when you run intensive applications your PSU is not able to provide enough power. You're running 2 GPUs here so you might wanna check that. Or your cards could be factory overclocked. It could also be your cable, which is unlikely but possible. Although you mentioned the temps I still think you should reapply the thermal paste just to make sure. Also, are you having problems with that particular game? If so, you might wanna check the settings and play around a bit.

Comment: My PSU is a Corsair CX600. I have tried in nVidia CP, setting the card to only use 1 GPU, without helping. I don't play games myself, and Runescape is the only game i have. I have lowered the sttings to the minimum and that didn't help either

Comment: On [NVIDIA's website](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-295/specifications) the minimum system power requirement is 680W. Although in practice—as shown in different tests—your card draws less power, I think that it has something to do with your PSU. It is possible. If it only happens when you're doing benchmark or playing games it is possible that your PSU is not able to provide enough power, therefore shutting itself off. If you have another PSU or GPU, you could try and see if your system shuts down with your other PSU or GPU as well.

Comment: The pc do not shut down, but keep awake, and show no input/signal (black screen). But i will test it tomorrow